# Smiley Badge effect and implications

Tags: bravely-default

In Bravely Default, one of the accessories you can buy (unlocked via Norende reconstruction) is the Smiley Badge.  The item states that it's effect is:

> A friendly badge that freezes your aggro level.

This leads me to a few questions then:

1. What is the 'default' aggro level of a character?  By wearing this badge will you never or only rarely be targeted?
2. If you wear the badge, and then use the pirate taunt skill or the ninja's detaunt skill, does it negate the effects?  Or will your threat go up/down and then lock in at the new level?
3. Are there true threat mechanics in Bravely Default?  I know there's a taunt skill (Pirate) and a threat deduction (Ninja) but do you earn aggro by attacking/healing?  Does this mean that the more damage a character does, the more likely they'll be targeted?  How does the threat system work?

Comment: The aggro level system works in a way that enemies will to target certain characters more during battle based on the actions (abilities and items) they take. The Smiley Badge simply negates any changes as a result of this for the equipped character, so it's great for mages to keep their aggro down. There's also the "Red Muleta" which maximizes the equipped character's aggro.

Comment: What actions increase aggro?  I use Agnes as a White Mage and thus have her default fairly often unless someone's taking a decent amount of damage.  Even so, she appears to be attacked about as often as Tiz and Ringabel, who attack (or cast or w/e) almost every turn...

Comment: Since the aggro value is hidden, it just feels random sometimes. From what I've noticed that doing damage of any sort (obviously) increases aggro and using support spells or item also generate a fair amount of aggro. Other than that, I'm not sure.